# NullPointerException while connecting to Mqtt on-line broker

Tags: java, mqtt, mosquitto, paho

I'm trying to connect to the on-line broker https://test.mosquitto.org/ using the code below and the Paho library in Java:

```
private final String brokerURI = "test.mosquitto.org:1883"; //should be changed to 8883 with SSL
try { //tentativo di creazione del client
        client = new MqttClient(brokerURI, idClient); <--NullPointerException here
        client.setCallback(new ClientCallback(codaTopic, codaMessaggi, finestra)); //set delle callback
        setConnectionOptions(); //set delle opzioni connessione
        client.connect(opzioni); //connessione al server
    } catch (MqttException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        System.err.println("Connessione fallita Client, riavviare il sistema.");
    }
```

Connection options are set here:

```
    private void setConnectionOptions() {
    opzioni = new MqttConnectOptions();
    opzioni.setAutomaticReconnect(true);
    opzioni.setCleanSession(false);
    opzioni.setConnectionTimeout(30);
    opzioni.setKeepAliveInterval(60);
}
```

but it continues to show a `NullPointerException` while creating the `MqttClient`. In particular the console displays:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttConnectOptions.validateURI(MqttConnectOptions.java:489)
at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttAsyncClient.<init>(MqttAsyncClient.java:291)
at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttAsyncClient.<init>(MqttAsyncClient.java:185)
at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient.<init>(MqttClient.java:226)
at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient.<init>(MqttClient.java:138)
at client.Client.run(Client.java:78)
```

How can i manage to connect and use SSL?
Surfing the net none of the tutorial or guides were useful, I already downloaded the `mosquitto.org.crt`file for SSL connection, but i don't know where to use it and I found no tutorials.

EDIT
Changing the BrokerUri to 
`private final String brokerURI = "tcp://test.mosquitto.org:1883"; //indirizzo broker`

the console shows the error

```
Client non connesso (32104)
at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ExceptionHelper.createMqttException(ExceptionHelper.java:31)
at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms.sendNoWait(ClientComms.java:166)
at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttAsyncClient.subscribe(MqttAsyncClient.java:835)
at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient.subscribe(MqttClient.java:322)
at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient.subscribe(MqttClient.java:315)
at client.Client.subscribe(Client.java:214)
at client.Client.run(Client.java:89)
```

while trying to subscribe to a Topic with the instruction

```
client.subscribe(topic, 1);
```

The topic argument is a String that contains the topic name.

Comment: And what is idClient?

Comment: The idCLient is a simple String, normally a name like "mario" or similar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mosquitto's URI needs the protocol. Taking a look at its source code, this is where your exception is being thrown, class `MqttConnectOpts.java` :

```
protected static int validateURI(String srvURI) {
    try {
        URI vURI = new URI(srvURI);
        if (!vURI.getPath().equals("")) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(srvURI);
        }
        if (vURI.getScheme().equals("tcp")) {
            return URI_TYPE_TCP;
        }
        else if (vURI.getScheme().equals("ssl")) {
            return URI_TYPE_SSL;
        }
        else if (vURI.getScheme().equals("local")) {
            return URI_TYPE_LOCAL;
        }
        else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(srvURI);
        }
    } catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(srvURI);
    }
}
```

So, it accepts 3 types of protocol prefixes: `tcp, ssl, local`. Regarding your example, you could try it this way:

- TCP

  ```
   private final String brokerURI = "tcp://test.mosquitto.org:1883";
  ```
- SSL

  ```
  private final String brokerURI = "ssl://test.mosquitto.org:8883";
  ```